# Not able to create new Iteration/Sprint, getting error - TF400491: user has no team write permissions

Tags: azure-devops

Team,

Not able to create new Iteration/Sprint in Azure Devops though I am part of **Team Administrator** Group. Read couple of article/forums but didn't get any solution.

Error- TF400491: user has no team write permissions

Please guide/help to resolve this

[image: TF400491: User has no team write permissions]

[Basic user unable to create a new sprint](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/basic-user-unable-to-create-a-new-sprint/809552)

Answer (score 1):

By default, Team Administrator may add existing iterations from [Project Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#open-project-settings-list-project-iterations) to [Team settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#open-team-settings-list-team-iterations). To create a new iteration, you need Project Administrator permissions: [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#prerequisites).

> To add an iteration path to a project, you must be a member of the
> Project Administrators group.

Or ask your admins to allow creating iterations for you:

> To add, edit, and manage iteration paths under a node, you must have
> one or more of the following permissions set to Allow for the node
> that you want to manage: Create child nodes, Delete this node, Edit
> this node, and View permissions for this node.